# Page goes blank on clicking dark mode button in React

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, tailwind-css

I am trying to implement dark mode in react, but my page goes blank on clicking the button.

```
"use client";

import Image from 'next/image'
import {BsFillMoonStarsFill} from 'react-icons/bs';
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? "dark" : ""}>
    <main className="px-10 dark:bg-gray-900">
      <section>

        {/* INDEX */}
        <nav className='py-10 mb-10 flex justify-between'>

          <h1 className='font-Baskerville text-xl'>Navigate To</h1>
          <ul className='flex items-center'>
            <li> <BsFillMoonStarsFill onClick={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} className='cursor-pointer text-xl'/> </li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
      </section>
    </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am able to get it to dark when I change the useState(false) to useSate(true).
Could someone please help me on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try to pass the logic to other function, like  this: 
const handleDarkMode=()=>{ setDarkMode(!darkMode)}
And pass the function on the click event: onClcik={handleDarkMode}